# Refer to static module asset in code

Tags: magento2, static-content

I've added some images to my module eg.

```
view/base/web/images/some-image.png
```

Having run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` I now see these have been published to the `pub` directory

```
pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Moxune_Moxune/images/some-image.png
```

I can access these from the web

```
https://mage2.local/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Moxune_Moxune/images/some-image.png
```

**My question**

What is the proper way to refer to these files in a `.phtml` file in my module?

It seems like putting the path from `/static` forward would be pretty hacky. My guess is there's some way to refer to the module and start off with `/images` or similar and provide a relative path to the files, but I'm not sure where to look for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, a few minutes later and I've found the answer. I'll leave this up as a Q/A style post as I think it could be helpful for other folks.

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('Moxune_Moxune/images/some-image.png')
```

FWIW I started off reading [this article from Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento-2-frontend-files-serving); it just didn't have the bit about how to refer to static assets like image files from templates.